# How to add each data frame created inside a loop to a separate sheet in excel?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

for(x in unique_seg){

bf <- data.frame(matrix(x,nrow =3,ncol =3))

write.xlsx(bf,'bf.xlsx', sheetname =x, append=True)
}

But I see only last loop is returned. How to get all sheets in 1 excel ?

Comment: You are creating a matrix from a single value?.  The `append = TRUE` should be correct rather than `True`

Comment: Can you specify the package used

Comment: Package used is xlsx. Though the above is some random dataframe I created. I actually wanted to know how can I store  each dataframe created inside a loop into an excel sheet

Comment: Do you want to return the output as well?

Comment: Please check the solution below

Comment: Yes, for example bf dataframe should be added in separate sheet for every x

Comment: It would be because you specified the `sheetname`

Answer (score 1):

If we want to return the output, create a `list` and assign the output to the `list`

```
lst1 <- vector('list', length(unique_seg))
names(lst1) <- unique_seg    

for(x in unique_seg){

   bf <- data.frame(matrix(x,nrow =3,ncol =3))

  write.xlsx(bf,'bf.xlsx', sheetname =x, append=TRUE)
  lst1[[x]] <- bf
  }
```